# Attempting to update db through aspx but it is not committing all fields to db

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I'm currently building a simple article library (or blog, whatever the preferred term is).
At the moment I can update the image fine but I am having trouble with the text. Silly I know as it should be a simple crud operation but a solution is evading my tiny mind. 
The image updates fine but the title and message fields do not seem to be updating and I have no idea why. Apologies if any of this is a little vague but I am at the end of my wits with this. It should have been simple, I have done it countless times before but I am now stuck and left feeling a little silly, so much so I think its time to call in an SO expert :)

My aspx:

```
 <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1">
        <asp:Label ID="lblError" runat="server"></asp:Label>

        <asp:FormView ID="frmArticle" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtTitle" Text='<%# Eval("EntryTitle") %>' runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Image ID="imgOriginal" runat="server" CssClass="img-responsive" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("ImageUrl") %>' />
        <asp:FileUpload ID="flupImg" runat="server" AllowMultiple="true" CssClass="form-control" />
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtMsg" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="25" Text='<%#Eval("Message")%>' ></asp:TextBox>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Update" CssClass="btn btn-block custBtn" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <asp:Button ID="btnCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" CssClass="btn btn-block custBtn" OnClick="btnCancel_Click" />
            </div>
        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:FormView>


    </div>
```

My code behind:

```
protected void editPost(string title, string msg)
{
    // Define ADO.NET objects
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Blog.ttc_BlogPosts", con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    // Define parameters for the Stored procedure
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Status", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50));
    cmd.Parameters["@Status"].Value = "UpdatePostMessage";
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Title", SqlDbType.NVarChar, -1));
    cmd.Parameters["@Title"].Value = title;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Message", SqlDbType.NVarChar, -1));
    cmd.Parameters["@Title"].Value = msg;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@EntryId", SqlDbType.Int));
    cmd.Parameters["@EntryId"].Value = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["postid"]);

    try
    {
        con.Open(); // Attempt to open the connection to the db
        int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (SqlException err)
    {
        lblError.Text = "Image update error" + err.Message;   // Catch exceptions
    }
    finally
    {
        con.Close();    // Close the connection, even if the attempt to open failed.
    }
}
protected void editImg(string imgUrl, string msg, string title)
{
    // Define ADO.NET objects
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Blog.ttc_BlogPosts", con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    // Define parameters for the Stored procedure
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Status", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50));
    cmd.Parameters["@Status"].Value = "UpdatePostImage";
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ImgUrl", SqlDbType.NVarChar, -1));
    cmd.Parameters["@ImgUrl"].Value = imgUrl;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Title", SqlDbType.NVarChar, -1));
    cmd.Parameters["@Title"].Value = title;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Message", SqlDbType.NVarChar, -1));
    cmd.Parameters["@Title"].Value = msg;        
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@EntryId", SqlDbType.Int));
    cmd.Parameters["@EntryId"].Value = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["postid"]);

    try
    {
        con.Open(); // Attempt to open the connection to the db
        int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (SqlException err)
    {
        lblError.Text = "Image update error: " + err.Message;   // Catch exceptions
    }
    finally
    {
        con.Close();    // Close the connection, even if the attempt to open failed.
    }
}

protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Find controls
    TextBox titleFeild = (TextBox)frmArticle.FindControl("txtTitle");
    TextBox msgFeild = (TextBox)frmArticle.FindControl("txtMsg");
    FileUpload fc = (FileUpload)frmArticle.FindControl("flupImg");
    Image postIm = (Image)frmArticle.FindControl("imgOriginal");
    // declare variables
    string aTitle, aMsg;
    // assign values to variables
    aTitle = titleFeild.Text;
    aMsg = msgFeild.Text;

    // call update functions
    if (fc.HasFile == false)
    {
       editPost(aTitle, aMsg);

    }
    else
    {
        string file = fc.PostedFile.FileName;
        // check extension
        string ext = Path.GetExtension(file);
        switch (ext.ToLower())
        {
            case ".png":
            case ".jpg":
            case ".jpeg":
                break;
            default: lblError.Text = "Sorry but this file type is not currently supported.";
                return;
        }
        // Using the following code the file will keep its original name.
        string sfn = Path.GetFileName(fc.PostedFile.FileName);
        string fpath = Path.Combine(upDir, sfn);
        // get name of original file            
        string urlImg = Path.Combine(Request.PhysicalApplicationPath, Server.MapPath(postIm.ImageUrl));
        // delete the original file
        try
        {
            File.Delete(urlImg);
            fc.PostedFile.SaveAs(fpath);
            editImg(@"~/Images/PostImages/" + sfn, aMsg, aTitle);


        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            lblError.Text = "Error  image: " + ex.Message;
        }


    }

}
```

My stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [Blog].[ttc_BlogPosts]
@Status varchar(50) = '' ,
@EntryId int = '',
@Title nvarchar(max) = '',
@Added datetime = '',
@Updated datetime = '',
@Message nvarchar(max) = '',
@ImgId int = '',
@ImgUrl nvarchar(max) = ''

AS
BEGIN
IF(@Status = 'Display')
begin
select Id, EntryTitle, Message, ImageUrl, DateAdded, LastEdited
from Blog.BlogEntry
order by DateAdded desc
end

else if(@Status = 'AddPost')
begin

insert into Blog.BlogEntry (EntryTitle, Message, DateAdded, ImageUrl)
values (@Title, @Message, GETDATE(), @ImgUrl)   
end
else if(@Status = 'DisplayPost')
begin
select EntryTitle, DateAdded, LastEdited, Message, ImageUrl
from Blog.BlogEntry
where Id = @EntryId
end
else if(@Status = 'UpdatePost')
begin
update Blog.BlogEntry
set EntryTitle = @Title, Message = @Message, LastEdited = GETDATE()
where Id = @EntryId
end 
else if(@Status = 'UpdatePostImage')
begin
update Blog.BlogEntry
set ImageUrl = @ImgUrl, LastEdited = GETDATE(), EntryTitle = @Title, Message = @Message
where Id = @EntryId
end
else if(@Status = 'DeletePost')
begin
delete from Blog.BlogEntry
where Id = @EntryId 
end


END
```

Any help that you guys are willing to offer will be very much appreciated. If any further details are required please do not hesitate to give me a shout ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found two issues in your code:

1. Wrong SQL parameters initialization. Notice that you initialize title two times, leaving `@Message` empty:

   ```
   cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Title", SqlDbType.NVarChar, -1));
   cmd.Parameters["@Title"].Value = title;
   cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Message", SqlDbType.NVarChar, -1));
   cmd.Parameters["@Title"].Value = msg;
   ```

   This affects both methods for post update and image update.
2. Missing case in stored proc. There is no line like

   ```
   else if(@Status = 'UpdatePostMessage')
   ```

   That means that call to `editMsg` does nothing.

On a general account, consider some refactoring of your code. Examples: `editMsg` and `editImg` has identical parts that could be written once and reused, SQLl would look nicer with `CASE`.

Comment: Hi Andrei, thank you so much for your help. No more late nigh coding for me haha. Would you be able to give me a little heads up with regard to converting my if / else if statements in SQL SERVER to Switch...Case? feel free to tell me where to go but, as they say, if you don't ask then you don't know ;)

Comment: @M_Griffiths, here is the [reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx). Result should look something like `CASE @Status WHEN ('Display') blah-blah CASE ('UpdatePostMessage') blah-blah ELSE default blah-blah`

Comment: Thanks again @Andrei. Your help in this matter has not only enabled me to fix the issue, it has also helped me stream line the code somewhat. Thanks again :)